# Rails Hyphens with numbers in filename doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 6.1.3.2
Puma 5.2.1

I have a very strange bug about assets.
If I name a js file like this : test-1111111.fr it is find by the server.

But if I add a other "1" (or any other digit) like this test-11111111.fr, I get a

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/test-11111111.js"
```

Anyone know where this problem comes from ?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: what environment you're running ? did you run `assets:precompile`, right ?

Comment: @LamPhan Development environment so I don't need to precompile. It's weird !